# Magento 2 - Add custom css steps

Tags: magento2, css, custom

I'm still having issues with adding some custom .css file to my custom theme in Magento 2.2.2

I have followed the known steps like: (I'm using the Claue theme)

1. Put magento in developer mode
2. In this file: `app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml` I've added this line: `<css src="css/file_custom.css"/>`
3. I've created the file_custom.css in: `app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/web/css`
4. When I deploy the files the css file is generated in: `pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/nl_NL/css as "file_custom.min.css"`.

But I can't get it to load... What am I doing wrong? Do I need to deploy the files in the first place when I'm in developer mode? I think I don't :) But how can I get **Magento** to load the file so I can add some custom styling?

Regards,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Into Magento_Theme/layout, create a new file default_head_blocks.xml 
with the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/file_custom.min.css" media="print" />
    </head>
</page>
```

Then use php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: Ah i see, so creating the extra .xml file does the trick, I thought that the default.xml did the same... The file is now loaded on the frontend. When I add code to the css file in app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/web/css do I have to deploy every time?

Comment: php bin/magento cache:clean

make sure to disable the browsing cache! it messes the output sometimes!

Comment: That doesn't work for me, the file in: pub/static/frontend/Mgs/claue/nl_NL/css, still remains empty...

Answer (score 0):

1) Go to `app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml` and add this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../vendor/magento/framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/custom.css" />
    </head>
</page>
```

**NB:** this custom css will be loaded in all pages.

2) add your **css** file in `app/design/frontend/Mgs/claue/web/css/custom.css`

3) clean cache : `php bin/magento cache:flush`
                 `php bin/magento cache:clean`